# Atom is giving an error when requesting data from a website

Tags: python, request, atom-editor

I'm requesting html data from a url using the request module in python.
Here is my code

```py
import requests

source = requests.get('http://coreyms.com')

print(source.text)
```

When I run this in atom it gives me an error;

```
File "/Users/isaacrichardson/Desktop/Python/Web Scraping/wiki.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(source.text)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 34807: ordinal not in range(128)
```

But when I run it in Treehouse workspaces it works fine and shows me the html data.
Whats wrong with atom or my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requests library is not installed correctly for atom or it is not useable for it. Installing it correctly will solve the issue.

If that doesn't work I would try to use the beautiful soup module:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
doc = BeautifulSoup(source.text, "html.parser")
print(doc.text)
```

Comment: I've installed using pip and pip3 but it still doesn't work that same error is coming up.

Comment: Why would atom not support this feature

Comment: Ok this seams really strange

Comment: When I use the .content it displays the html but when I use the .text it gives that error it's like there an error with .text method only in atom

Answer (score 0):

`requests` [guesses the encoding](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content) when you access the `.text` attribute of the response object.
If you know the encoding of the response beforehand you should explicitly set it before accessing the `.text` attribute:

```
import requests

source = requests.get('http://coreyms.com')
source.encoding = 'utf-8'  # or whatever the encoding is
print(source.text)
```

Alternatively, you can also work with `.content` to access the binary response conent and decode it yourself.

You may want to verify if the encodings are indeed guessed differently in your IDEs by simply printing `source.encoding`.